# SSH session with SOCKS5 proxy does not logout/exit properly

Tags: ssh, socks5

It 'hangs' if I use the 'exit' command, and I have to terminate the terminal. I am using it on a Mac. I use the -D option to SSH over a port.

Edit: This happens only when I have used this proxy/connection in my browser to send requests to the remote server. If I try to exit the session without doing so, it logs out gracefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because SSH won't exit if there are outstanding connections going through the tunnel/proxy.

If I quit the browser (close all windows), SSH exits normally. All TCP and X11 connections need to be closed before exiting the SSH session.

I found no options to change this, so I assume we can do nothing to prevent this behavior.